# Unable to install libgnutls-dev

Tags: 14.04, apt

Seem that I have dependency error but don't know how to resolved it.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and tried to install libgnutls-dev but got an error as follow:

```
    lutfijw@HTPC:~$ sudo apt-get install libgnutls-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgnutls-dev : Depends: libtasn1-6-dev but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libp11-kit-dev (>= 0.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The following is my /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
lutfijw@HTPC:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20140722.2)]/ trusty main restricted
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org wheezy main non-free
# deb ftp://ftp.deb-multimedia.org wheezy main non-free
deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org stable main non-free
# deb ftp://ftp.deb-multimedia.org stable main non-free
# deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu vivid main universe
```

My /etc/apt/sources.list/* as follow:

```
lutfijw@HTPC:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/node.js/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/deluge-team/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gstreamer-developers/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gstreamer-developers/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gstreamer-developers/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gstreamer-developers/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linrunner/tlp/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/transmissionbt/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/transmissionbt/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/transmissionbt/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/transmissionbt/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
```

I'm also tried to install the dependency libtasn1-6-dev and libp11-kit-dev but still having the same issue. I'm also tried to use apt-get -f but still not work.

Please advise how to resolve it.

Comment: Post the output of `apt-cache policy libgnutls-dev`